# must i handle session garbage?

Tags: php

when the user closes his browser, usually he losts the cookie that marks the session. but the file in the server is not deleted and remains there, useless.

do i have to handle it? or it's a server's business?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a server's business. PHP has a "garbage collector" mechanism for them. See the [session.gc_probability](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability), [session.gc_divisor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) and [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You should never take care of it - it is php internals' business.

Comment: the "never" is uncalled for. You generally don't have to would give you a +1.